# How Do You Skip Whitespace In ANTLR Parser Rules?

Tags: parsing, whitespace, antlr

I'm implementing an ANTLR grammar in which I want to completely ignore whitespace (other than newlines) in every context. Given that, I've included the following rule:

`WS: [ \t]+ -> skip ;`

However, when the rule `fieldX: 'X:' INT NEWLINE;` attempts to parse "X: 1", I still get the following error:

`extraneous input ' ' expecting INT`

My understanding is that I'm getting this error because fieldX is a parser rule, and my WS rule will only be effective for lexer rules. I looked at a few similar questions on here and the only concrete solution I could find was to just convert fieldX into a lexer rule. However, I have a number of similar rules that I would need to convert. Is there any way to get a parser rule to skip whitespace other than just converting it to a lexer rule?

Comment: "My understanding is that I'm getting this error because fieldX is a parser rule, and my WS rule will only be effective for lexer rules." It's the other way around: if fieldX were a lexer rule, it wouldn't care about skipped tokens because it'd be consuming characters, not tokens. But since it's a parser rule, it won't see any skipped tokens, meaning that the ' ' that the parser is complaining about is not a WS token. You probably have another lexer rule that matches spaces and isn't skipped, possibly a literal somewhere. As always, you should post a proper [MCVE].

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense now. My grammar has a rule that uses the wildcard character, which I did not realize also matches whitespace. When I moved that rule below my WS rule, it resolved the issue.

Comment: When asking about questions on Antlr, please post the complete grammar. I also recommend printing out the tokens to see what the lexer is doing, and look over them carefully. You will need to "reset()" the lexer if you do, so that the lexer restarts from the beginning of the char stream.

Answer (score 0):

As sepp2k suggested, I had the following rule elsewhere in my grammar:
`TEXT: .?+;`. I didn't think the wildcard character would match whitespace, but it does. By moving this rule to come after my WS rule, I was able to solve the issue.